# How to find and fix performance issues due to GC in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, garbage-collection, profiling

I have a small program written in Haskell for finding words in a Boggle puzzle ([code here](https://github.com/gnuvince/deboggler), [blog post here](http://cs.mcgill.ca/~vfoley1/posts/2013-12-27-deboggler-part1.html)).  I recently made a portion of the code, a depth-first search, parallel using `Control.Parallel.Strategies`.  Running the program with `-N2` speeds up the program, but going above two threads brings down the performance.  At `-N8` the program is about 4x slower than the sequential version.

Looking at the output of `+RTS -s` and of the threads behavior in ThreadScope, it is clear that garbage collection is the main culprit, as it takes up to 45% of the execution time.  Now that I know this, how can I find which functions are the most likely culprits, and are there general tips or techniques in Haskell for fixing such leaks?

Comment: Is it GC that's the slow part, or cores idling while waiting for a stop-the-world GC to run? This should be pretty easy to see from the ThreadScope graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest optimization here would be to move the trie lookups inside the `parMap`. It's a significant part of all the work done, so doing it sequentially hurts the scaling quite a bit. We could use the following function instead of `findWords`:

```
process :: Dict -> B.ByteString -> G.Graph -> (Int, Int) -> [B.ByteString]
process dict board graph (n, d) = 
    [ word |
        path <- G.dfs d n graph,
        let word = pathToWord board path,
        T.contains word dict ]
```

And then call `parMap rdeepseq (process dict board graph)` in `main`.

This alone provides a 2x overall speedup on my system with `-N4`, resulting in a 0,65 sec runtime on an i7 3770, and it scales reasonably from 1,2 sec with `-N2` and 1,7 sec at `-N1`.

For the more sophisticated profiling options, you should look at the [GHC Manual](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/users_guide/profiling.html) and [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/profiling-and-optimization.html).

I personally like to use a "quick and dirty" profiling method on small programs like this: I create or derive [`NFData`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq-1.3.0.1/docs/Control-DeepSeq.html) instances for my data types, then force my structures or parts of my program with `return $!! something` in the main function, then run with `+RTS -s` for diagnostics. Accordingly, in your original program building the trie took 0,4 sec and generating the paths took 0,6 sec, and both tasks were quite GC-heavy.

Note that the GC load is actually normal here. After all, your trie has `Data.Map` nodes, and you do lots of insertions there when building the trie, and you also generate 1,6 million paths with the involvement of `Data.Set`-s for keeping record of visited nodes.

In other words, the GC's just doing its honest work, and the program is slow because it has a suboptimal algorithm. A faster way would be to just iterate over all the words in the dictionary and do a breadth-first search to determine whether a word is in the Boggle table. This is a promising strategy because:

- We can discard most of the words very quickly (because they start with a letter that's not in the table).
- There are usually much less words than there are possible paths.

A while ago I wrote a very small [Boggle program](https://gist.github.com/AndrasKovacs/5821189) in Haskell that works this way. It is about 20-25 times faster than your solution on my system, and without any parallelization as it is currently.

A potentially even faster way would be to use the trie "properly", i. e. to do a constrained depth-first search on the table, utilizing the trie's structure to prune any paths that cannot possibly yield valid words. I think though that in practice it would be hard to make it faster than my "dumb" method, because tries for realistically sized dictionaries have a tendency to absolutely murder CPU cache. Static tries though can be spectacularly compressed to directed acyclic words graphs, but that requires another bit of work.

Comment: Good idea about using a BFS approach; I considered it briefly, but to generate the paths, and since it would give the same paths, I didn't consider the idea further.  I'll give it a try and report back.